# Geoserver WMS defaults to Mollweide projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

We have a WMS on Geoserver (version 2.6.1) which we are using to view in QGIS. For some reason when importing to QGIS it defaults to World Mollweide (EPSG:54009). The process is as follows:

Add connection:

[image: Add WMS connection to QGIS]

With the path http://www.ga.gov.au/geophysics-rockpropertypub-gws/ga_rock_properties_wms/ows

[image: WMS Connection Settings]

This gives us all our WMS Layers:

[image: QGIS Browser with WMS Layers]

And if we add a couple:

[image: Legend with gamma short spaced density and dry bulk density]

We get a strange projection for the project:

[image: Project coordinate system]

If we look at the properties of the gamma short spaced density layer

[image: Layer properties of gamma short spaced density]

It too has defaulted to World Mollweide. The layer source string is as follows:

crs=EPSG:54009&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=gamma_short_spaced_density&styles=&url=http://www.ga.gov.au/geophysics-rockpropertypub-gws/ga_rock_properties_wms/ows

So what is the reason for this? We want the default to be EPSG:4326 at the minimum, although we would prefer EPSG:4283. How can we fix this? Is it a problem with QGIS or the  WMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the WMS from the "Add Layer(s) from a WM(T)S Server" button in QGIS Desktop will let you set the CRS for the layer added.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's the best solution. Apparently a fix to the drag-and-drop method is coming in QGIS 2.8.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. I was using the drag-and-drop option in 2.6 and it always defaulted to the first supported EPSG in GetCapabilities list.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Base layer crs]

If you click on the Globe icon and change your base crs to EPSG:4326, it should change the default CRS whenever you add a new layer

Comment: I have found that simply changing the project coordinate system forces reprojecting of the tiles coming from Geoserver, so the image doesn't look very good...